# Problem with session attributes in JSP EL using Spring MVC

Tags: jsp, spring-mvc, jstl, session-variables, el

I'm trying to show a session attribute "userSession" in a jsp page using JSP EL, but it returns null (case 1). Request attributes are shown properly in EL expressions though.

Using java scriptlet instead, behaves as shown in cases 2 and 3:

1. `<c:out value="${userSession}"/>` \\Returns null
2. `<c:out value='<%=request.getSession().getAttribute("userSession")%>'/>`
   \\Works fine - returns session attribute
3. `<c:out value='<%=session.getAttribute("userSession")%>'/>`
   \\Throws exception: cannot find variable session

Exception of case 3 may be related to case 1 problem, something like not recognizing the session variable for some reason and that affecting the EL expression then.

I'm using Spring MVC 2.5 and JSTL 1.1.2.

I can post anything else needed to clarify the problem.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Fixed. Problem was with a `<%@ page session="false" %>` directive found in an include.jsp used by my page, which I removed from that global place.

It prevents a jsp page from access to session scope variables. So only `<%=request.getSession().getAttribute("foo")%>` works in that case...

Answer (score 9):

What does:

```
<c:out value="${sessionScope.userSession}"/>
```

or

```
<c:out value="${sessionScope['userSession']}"/>
```

give?

Comment: The same with `<c:out value="${userSession}"/>` : null

Comment: Try the sessionScope variable as indicated above.

Comment: What happens when you set a session var right before you print it: `<c:set var="userSession" scope="session" value="Hello"/>`?

Comment: I'm getting the following exception:

java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot access session scope in page that does not participate in any session

Answer (score 4):

`<c:out value="${sessionScope}"/>` or just `${sessionScope}` list all the attributes in portlet application scope.

so, You can try to get your attribut with this expression !