# get session variable Array list into Display Tag

Tags: jsp, displaytag

Hi I have ArrayList get from session in jsp.

```
<%java.util.ArrayList<Organisation> OrganisationList1 = 
                    (java.util.ArrayList<DAOrganisation>) 
                   request.getSession().getAttribute("organisationArray");%>
```

Then I try to get this array list and display by using Display Tag.

```
<display:table class="displayTable" id="orgList"
                name="OrganisationList" requestURI="" pagesize="13"
                defaultsort="1" sort="list">
                <display:column property="organisationName"
                title="Organisation Name" sortable="true" headerClass="sortable"  paramId="organisationId" paramProperty="organisationId" />
                <display:column property="description" title="Description">
                </display:column>
            </display:table>
```

But it doesn't show anything in Display Table. I am add pagination to the old coding of other. So, I need follow the structure and can't change it. As far as I know , I can use ArrayList directly with Display Tag. So, I just want to ***Display the Array List from Session using Display Tag***. Thanks.

Edited: In the old code, he tried to convert into Organisation Java Bean by looping and use to display one by one.

Stack Trace:

> org.apache.jasper.JasperException: An exception occurred processing
>   JSP page /organisationlist.jsp at line 81
>
> 78:        79:  80:        81:             82:               83:
>
> Stacktrace:
>     org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.handleJspException(JspServletWrapper.java:519)
>     org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:422)
>     org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:313)
>     org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:260)
>     javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
>     org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ServletDispatcherResult.doExecute(ServletDispatcherResult.java:154)
>     org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.StrutsResultSupport.execute(StrutsResultSupport.java:186)
>     com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.executeResult(DefaultActionInvocation.java:361)
>     com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:265)
>     com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.DefaultWorkflowInterceptor.doIntercept(DefaultWorkflowInterceptor.java:163)
>     com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:87)
>     com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:236)
>     com.opensymphony.xwork2.validator.ValidationInterceptor.doIntercept(ValidationInterceptor.java:249)
>     org.apache.struts2.interceptor.validation.AnnotationValidationInterceptor.doIntercept(AnnotationValidationInterceptor.java:68)
>     com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:87)
>     com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:236)
>     com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ConversionErrorInterceptor.intercept(ConversionErrorInterceptor.java:122)
>     com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:236)
>     com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ParametersInterceptor.doIntercept(ParametersInterceptor.java:195)
>     com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:87)
>     com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:236)
>     com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ParametersInterceptor.doIntercept(ParametersInterceptor.java:195)
>     com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:87)
>     com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:236)
>     com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.StaticParametersInterceptor.intercept(StaticParametersInterceptor.java:148)
>     com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:236)
>     org.apache.struts2.interceptor.CheckboxInterceptor.intercept(CheckboxInterceptor.java:93)
>     com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:236)
>     org.apache.struts2.interceptor.FileUploadInterceptor.intercept(FileUploadInterceptor.java:235)
>     com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:236)
>     com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ModelDrivenInterceptor.intercept(ModelDrivenInterceptor.java:89)
>     com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:236)
>     com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ScopedModelDrivenInterceptor.intercept(ScopedModelDrivenInterceptor.java:128)
>     com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:236)
>     org.apache.struts2.interceptor.ProfilingActivationInterceptor.intercept(ProfilingActivationInterceptor.java:104)
>     com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:236)
>     org.apache.struts2.interceptor.debugging.DebuggingInterceptor.intercept(DebuggingInterceptor.java:267)
>     com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:236)
>     com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ChainingInterceptor.intercept(ChainingInterceptor.java:126)
>     com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:236)
>     com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.PrepareInterceptor.doIntercept(PrepareInterceptor.java:138)
>     com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:87)
>     com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:236)
>     com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.I18nInterceptor.intercept(I18nInterceptor.java:148)
>     com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:236)
>     org.apache.struts2.interceptor.ServletConfigInterceptor.intercept(ServletConfigInterceptor.java:164)
>     com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:236)
>     com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.AliasInterceptor.intercept(AliasInterceptor.java:128)
>     com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:236)
>     com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ExceptionMappingInterceptor.intercept(ExceptionMappingInterceptor.java:176)
>     com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:236)
>     org.apache.struts2.impl.StrutsActionProxy.execute(StrutsActionProxy.java:52)
>     org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher.serviceAction(Dispatcher.java:468)
>     org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.FilterDispatcher.doFilter(FilterDispatcher.java:395)
>
> root cause
>
> java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot access session scope in page
>   that does not participate in any session
>     org.apache.jasper.runtime.PageContextImpl.doGetAttribute(PageContextImpl.java:264)
>     org.apache.jasper.runtime.PageContextImpl.getAttribute(PageContextImpl.java:249)
>     org.displaytag.util.LookupUtil.getBeanValue(LookupUtil.java:100)
>     org.displaytag.tags.TemplateTag.evaluateExpression(TemplateTag.java:84)
>     org.displaytag.tags.TableTag.initParameters(TableTag.java:932)
>     org.displaytag.tags.TableTag.doStartTag(TableTag.java:767)
>     org.apache.jsp.organisationlist_jsp._jspService(organisationlist_jsp.java:223)
>     org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
>     javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
>     org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:386)
>     org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:313)
>     org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:260)
>     javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
>     org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ServletDispatcherResult.doExecute(ServletDispatcherResult.java:154)
>     org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.StrutsResultSupport.execute(StrutsResultSupport.java:186)
>     com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.executeResult(DefaultActionInvocation.java:361)
>     com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:265)
>     com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.DefaultWorkflowInterceptor.doIntercept(DefaultWorkflowInterceptor.java:163)
>     com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:87)
>     com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:236)
>     com.opensymphony.xwork2.validator.ValidationInterceptor.doIntercept(ValidationInterceptor.java:249)
>     org.apache.struts2.interceptor.validation.AnnotationValidationInterceptor.doIntercept(AnnotationValidationInterceptor.java:68)
>     com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:87)
>     com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:236)
>     com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ConversionErrorInterceptor.intercept(ConversionErrorInterceptor.java:122)
>     com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:236)
>     com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ParametersInterceptor.doIntercept(ParametersInterceptor.java:195)
>     com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:87)
>     com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:236)
>     com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ParametersInterceptor.doIntercept(ParametersInterceptor.java:195)
>     com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:87)
>     com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:236)
>     com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.StaticParametersInterceptor.intercept(StaticParametersInterceptor.java:148)
>     com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:236)
>     org.apache.struts2.interceptor.CheckboxInterceptor.intercept(CheckboxInterceptor.java:93)
>     com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:236)
>     org.apache.struts2.interceptor.FileUploadInterceptor.intercept(FileUploadInterceptor.java:235)
>     com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:236)
>     com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ModelDrivenInterceptor.intercept(ModelDrivenInterceptor.java:89)
>     com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:236)
>     com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ScopedModelDrivenInterceptor.intercept(ScopedModelDrivenInterceptor.java:128)
>     com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:236)
>     org.apache.struts2.interceptor.ProfilingActivationInterceptor.intercept(ProfilingActivationInterceptor.java:104)
>     com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:236)
>     org.apache.struts2.interceptor.debugging.DebuggingInterceptor.intercept(DebuggingInterceptor.java:267)
>     com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:236)
>     com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ChainingInterceptor.intercept(ChainingInterceptor.java:126)
>     com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:236)
>     com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.PrepareInterceptor.doIntercept(PrepareInterceptor.java:138)
>     com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:87)
>     com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:236)
>     com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.I18nInterceptor.intercept(I18nInterceptor.java:148)
>     com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:236)
>     org.apache.struts2.interceptor.ServletConfigInterceptor.intercept(ServletConfigInterceptor.java:164)
>     com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:236)
>     com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.AliasInterceptor.intercept(AliasInterceptor.java:128)
>     com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:236)
>     com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ExceptionMappingInterceptor.intercept(ExceptionMappingInterceptor.java:176)
>     com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:236)
>     org.apache.struts2.impl.StrutsActionProxy.execute(StrutsActionProxy.java:52)
>     org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher.serviceAction(Dispatcher.java:468)
>     org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.FilterDispatcher.doFilter(FilterDispatcher.java:395)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

JSP tags don't use scriptlet variables. They use JSP EL expressions. scriptlets are something from the past and should not be used anymore in JSPs.

Just use

```
<display:table name="${organisationArray}" ...>
```

Or, if you want to be more explicit:

```
<display:table name="${sessionScope.organisationArray}" ...>
```

Comment: I still can't get the data in the Display Tag. In the Java class, set the session attribute like that `sess.setAttribute("organisationArray", organisationArray);` Thanks

Comment: Depending on which version of the taglib you're using, it might be name="sessionScope.organisationArray"

Comment: Hi , I am using Display Tag Lib 1.2. When I use `<display:table name="${organisationArray}" ...>` like that, it said Nothing to display. But when I try like that  `name="sessionScope.organisationArray"`, it gives me Jasper exception.

Comment: Show us the stack trace of the exception, and the taglib directive used at the top of the JSP to declare that you're using the displaytag library.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I just miss out to check directive declared in common page used by my page. In common page session = false. So, I just enable it `session=true` again. and it works well with both `<display:table name="${sessionScope.organisationArray}" ...>`and `<display:table name="sessionScope.organisationArray" ...>`. Thanks again. and Thanks to this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4730790/problem-with-session-attributes-in-jsp-el-using-spring-mvc) because it makes me aware of this error. :)