# Accessing c:var variable inside sql:param

Tags: jsp, jsp-tags

I am facing problem in accessing the jsp "core tag" in jsp "sql tag" for a query.

Code :

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>

<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/sql" prefix="sql" %> 

<sql:setDataSource
    var="myDS"
    driver="org.postgresql.Driver"
    url="jdbc:postgresql://localhost:xxxx/xyz"
    user="xyz" password="test123"
/>
<% String user_Email = session.getAttribute("email").toString(); 
   out.println("Email = "+ user_Email); %>
  <c:set var="emailid" value= "${user_Email}"/>

<sql:query var="listUsers"   dataSource="${myDS}">

    SELECT * FROM developer_apikey_registration where email_id = ?  ;
    <sql:param value="${emailid}"/>


</sql:query>
```

I am not able to get the email value here. Although I checked that it is coming correctly in the session attribute.

Please help me in this regard. I am new to JSP
Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Have you checked for stack trace (i mean your server log) and also check whether you have added headers for jstl

Comment: No error, I checked with hardcoded value at <sql:param value="test@gmail.com"> is giving me the output as expected. I have already put the core library in class path and its working fine.

Comment: Does this code `out.println("Email = "+ user_Email);`prints the value

Comment: yes, it prints the text entered. It will be printed on the browser itself.

Comment: Then the problem is you are not setting the value in proper manner, try my code

Comment: Please post your code. I will try

Comment: Comment below my answer if you need any help

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/sql" prefix="sql" %> 
<sql:setDataSource
    var="myDS"
    driver="org.postgresql.Driver"
    url="jdbc:postgresql://localhost:xxxx/xyz"
    user="xyz" password="test123"
/>
  <c:set var="emailid" value= "${sessionScope[user_Email]}"/>
<sql:query var="listUsers"   dataSource="${myDS}">
    SELECT * FROM developer_apikey_registration where email_id = ?  ;
    <sql:param value="${emailid}"/>
</sql:query>
```

Hope this helps !!

Comment: Checked, still not working.... Same issue, I can't see the email getting assigned to the sql param. I don't see any error as well in the server.

Comment: Any exceptions . Please check you have anything like this `<%@ page session="false" %>` directive in your jsp

Comment: No, if I will use that then how I will get the session.getAttribute("email") value in the above code.... Nothing like that is mentioned. By default it is true.

Comment: No even in that case it works for getAttribute . [Check here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4730790/problem-with-session-attributes-in-jsp-el-using-spring-mvc)

Comment: Next thing to check whether EL is working for you , check printing `${sessionScope[user_Email]}"` this

Comment: How to print "${sessionScope[user_Email]}" ? I wrote it in <%= %> tag within double quote. It prints ${sessionScope[user_Email]}. Without double quote, I get error in compilation

Comment: The code edited above should work as i have tried it in my local machine . what error you got ?

Comment: No, not working, I checked, There is some issue with accessing the value in sql tag. Either the assignment is not proper or may the jar I attached have some issue..... It is still working fine with static value. There is no error I can  see in the server, So not able to debug as well...

Comment: you may try clean and build or re-install your jar files

Comment: Nothing helped till now... Thanks for support, Leaving the topic here... Will debug in eve. Issue still not resolved. I don't see any error, But sure there is issue with the assignment to the c: var.

Answer (score 0):

```
    <%String pkgName=null;%>
    <%String apiKey=null;%>
    <% String user_Email = session.getAttribute("email").toString(); 
       String email = null;
     if(session.isNew())
        {
             RequestDispatcher rdp=request.getRequestDispatcher("index.jsp");
             rdp.forward(request, response);
        }
    %>
   <%= user_Email %> // To check if email is not null

    <div align="center">
    <table border="1" cellpadding="5">
        <caption><h2>List of users</h2></caption>
        <tr>
            <th>Email</th>
            <th>Package Name</th>
            <th>API Key</th>
            <th> Operation </th>
        </tr>


  <%
       try
       {
         Connection con=DbConn.getConnect();
         Statement st=con.createStatement(); 
         String q1="select * from  developer_apikey_registration where email_id ='"+user_Email+"'";
         ResultSet rs1=st.executeQuery(q1);

         while(rs1.next())
                {

                   email = rs1.getString("email_id");
                   pkgName = rs1.getString("package_name");
                   apiKey = rs1.getString("apikey");
                   %>

                   <tr>
                <td><%=email%></td>
                <td><%=pkgName%></td>
                <td><%=apiKey%></td>
                <td><input type ="button" name="editBtn" id ="edtBtn" value="Edit">
        <input type ="button" name="deleteBtn" id ="delBtn" value="Delete"> </td>
            </tr>
    <%               
                }

       }  
       catch(Exception e)
               {
                e.printStackTrace();
           }


    %>

   </table>
</div>
```